# Scale three symbols to the same size

Tags: symbols, scale

I would like to use 3 different symbols, "circle", "cross" and "circle with cross"

I have found the following symbols `$\times$`, `$\otimes$`, `$\circ$`, `$\bigcirc$`.
The cross (`\times`) and the circle with cross (`\otimes`) are the same scale but the circle (`\circ` or `\bigcirc`) are scaled differently.

How do I set the scale so the tree symbols are the same size?

I get this output

[image]

Comment: Well, isn't it quite obvious that `\bigcirc` is larger than the other symbols? And `\circ` is meant for something like in a dot etc. product rather

Comment: Well then what is the correct command for a circle?

Comment: i haven't compared the size, but it seems that `\varbigcirc` from `stmaryrd` might be close.  (this was found in the "comprehensive symbols list", `texdoc comprehensive`, looking in places where i already knew there might be circles.  it's not entirely obvious.)

Comment: I have just tried \varbigcirc and unfortunately it is almost the same size as \bigcirc. 
Which means it is still bigger than \times and \otimes.
But thank you for trying :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wasysym` package has `\ocircle` which seems of the correct width to me:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
    $\times$

    $\otimes$

    $\ocircle$
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*

If you simply have to use this symbols as a sort of checkmarks in a table, you can use `\scalebox` loading `graphicx` package.

Here I've created three macros (`\mytimes`, `\myotimes` and `\myocircle`) for convenience:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\mytimes}{\scalebox{4}{$\times$}}
\newcommand{\myotimes}{\scalebox{4}{$\otimes$}}
\newcommand{\myocircle}{\scalebox{4}{$\ocircle$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4em}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Legend of symbols}\\
\midrule
Expected result & \myocircle \\
Calculated result & \mytimes \\
Expected result equal to calculated one & \myotimes \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!
If you should scale them, would you use "\small{}" / "\huge{}" or something else?

Comment: @Jonas Are you using those symbols as math operators?

Comment: Well i'm not sure. 
I'm going to use them in a table to denote results. 
Expected result is shown with a circle
The calculated result is shown whit a cross
If expected result is equal to calculated the cross-circle is used.
My problem is the symbols are very hard to see in the table, so I would like to make them a little bigger.

Comment: @Jonas It's also easier if you don't have to use them as math operator, you can simply use `\scalebox`. I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: Thank you!
I have created a command, so I don't have to use \scalebox every time.

\newcommand{\Otimes}{\scalebox{1.5}{$\otimes$}}

Comment: @Jonas I was editing my answer while you was commenting it... However we had the same idea!